# How to edit "Notify me when this product is in stock" text on product page

Tags: product, magento2.1.6, product-alert

when i enable "Allow Alert When Product Comes Back in Stock" on magneto admin backend and it shows "Notify me when this product is in stock" on product page.
I want to edit the product alert text on front but how? i have no idea, please help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there's another easier way which is Inline Translate.

Translating is simply just changing 1 text to another.

You can use Inline Translate or Translate using the i18n folder that Magento provided.

More information can be found here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Comment: It's true. I think i should rewrite translate file not to edit code.

Answer (score 2):

Override
`vendor/magento/module-product-alert/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`
to your theme and
change the *setSignupLabel* in *productalert.stock* block

Comment: Thanks, and it works after clean magento cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on your Template Path Hints and see which file it is.

Check this link: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/template-path-hints.html

And when you are editing you should follow Magento's best practice.

**Template customization walkthrough**

**To customize a template:**

1. Locate the template which is associated with the page/block you want to change using template hints.
2. Copy the template to your theme folder according to the template storing convention.
3. Make the required changes.

**To add a new template in a theme:**

1. Add a template in your theme directory according to the template storing convention.
2. Assign your template to a block in the corresponding layout file.

Ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html

Comment: I haven't use this before and it looks good. Thanks your information.